# I am having problems with getting my window formatted. I have tried all of the pack combinations I can think of but no success

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

Here is the code I currently am using but it produces a mess.

1. the space  between the left treeview and the scollbar is to wide
2. the buttons should be aligned in the center of the window to the right of the left scroll bar.
3. the right treeview is too low.

Here is my current code:

```
nbWindow.add(frmLink, text="Link")
treLink1 = ttk.Treeview(frmLink)
treLink1["show"] = "headings"
treLink1["columns"] = ("one", "two")
treLink1.column("one", width=200)
treLink1.column("two", width=20)
treLink1.heading("one", text="Field Name")
treLink1.heading("two", text="Field Key")

# attach scrollbar
scrollbarLink = Scrollbar(frmLink)
scrollbarLink.config(command=treLink1.yview)
treLink1.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbarLink.set)
treLink1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=30, pady=30, fill="both")
scrollbarLink.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=0, pady=30, fill=Y)

#add movement buttons
#button to add new field
btAddFieldLink = Button(frmLink, text="Add Field")
btAddFieldLink.config(height=2, width=10)
btAddFieldLink.pack(pady=30, fill=Y)
# button move down,
btMoveDownLink = Button(frmLink, text="Move Down")
btMoveDownLink.config(height=2, width=10)
btMoveDownLink.pack(pady=0)
# button move up
btMoveUpLink = Button(frmLink, text="  Move Up  ")
btMoveUpLink.config(height=2, width=10)
btMoveUpLink.pack()
# button delete field
btDeleteFieldLink = Button(frmLink, text="Delete Field")
btDeleteFieldLink.config(height=2, width=10)
btDeleteFieldLink.pack()


#format link view
treLink3 = ttk.Treeview(frmLink)
treLink3["show"] = "headings"
treLink3["columns"] = ("one", "two")
treLink3.column("one", width=5)
treLink3.column("two", width=200)
treLink3.heading("one", text="TName")
treLink3.heading("two", text="Field Name")

# attach scrollbar
scrollbarLink1 = Scrollbar(frmLink)
scrollbarLink1.config(command=treLink3.yview)
treLink3.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbarLink1.set)

treLink3.pack(side=RIGHT)
scrollbarLink.pack(side=LEFT)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your entire code!!!

Comment: @TheMaker, posting your entire code is discouraged on SE, and should be reduced to [mre].

Comment: Sorry but even if it was not discouraged I would not be sharing my complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding all the groups of elements in their own frame?

Something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def createlabels(root, stack):
    for i in stack:
        tk.Label(root,text=i).pack()

stack1 = ['one','two','three','four']
stack2 = ['five','six','seven','eight']
stack3 = ['nine','ten','eleven','twelve']

f1 = tk.Frame(root, bg="#ff0000")
f2 = tk.Frame(root, bg="#00ff00")
f3 = tk.Frame(root, bg="#0000ff")

createlabels(f1,stack1)
createlabels(f2,stack2)
createlabels(f3,stack3)


f1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT)
f2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
f3.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I finally got it close just  needs a little more touching. Used a combination of things but the most was the fill property changes. I finally just tried them all and got a combination that worked.